# Как найти сумму чисел из массива в java?

Tags: java, массивы

Пытаюсь получить сумму всех чисел.

Например:

```java
public static void testArray() {
    int myArray[] = {3, 5, 7, 12};
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        int i2 = i + 1;
        if (i2 >= myArray.length - 1) {
            i2 = 0;
            i2 = 0;
        }
        int sum = myArray[i] + myArray[i2];
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Да, да, я знаю, что этот код - кусок бреда, который даже близко не выполняет свою функцию, но я уже голову себе сломал и далеко я не математик (и не программист).

Как же мне найти сумму чисел в массиве, при условии что длина массива может быть произвольной, а числа в нем разные, не имеющие какой либо последовательности?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Честно не понял вопроса. В начале говорится - пытаюсь получить сумму некоторых чисел... а что значит некоторых?? Если всех чисел, то это очень просто сделать:

```java
public static void testArray() {
    int myArray[] = {3, 5, 7, 12};
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + myArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Ну да, наверное всех. Не так выразился. Прощу прощения, имелось ввиду, что в массиве может быть абсолютно разные числа, которые идут не по порядку и все такое.

Comment: Я написал вам код, который суммирует все числа в массиве ,какой бы длины он ни был.

Comment: Блин так просто! Спасибо!

Comment: Нажмите только это спасибо))) Если ответ вам подошел, то заодно выбор ответа, чтобы вопрос закрылся)))

Comment: sum += myArray[i];

Answer (score 16):

В Java 8 можно в 1 строку с помощью `stream`

```
int myArray[] = {3, 5, 7, 12};
int total = IntStream.of(myArray).sum();
```

аналогично можно использовать класс `Arrays`

```
Arrays.stream(myArray).sum()
```

Метод `stream` имеет перегрузки для примитивных типов и обобщенный вид, что подойдет для массивов других типов.

Answer (score 2):

Существует несколько способов найти сумму элементов в массиве:

- Используя [Java 8 Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) (сначала с помощью метода [`Arrays::stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) преобразовываем массив в поток целых чисел, затем получаем сумму этого потока методом [`Stream::sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--))

  ```
  int array[] = {3, 5, 7, 12};
  int sum = Arrays.stream(array).sum();
  ```
- Цикл по элементам (`for-each` цикл)

  ```
  int array[] = {3, 5, 7, 12};
  int sum = 0;
  for (int element : array)
      sum += element;
  ```
- Цикл с использование индексов

  ```
  int array[] = {3, 5, 7, 12};
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
      sum += array[i];
  ```

Онлайн примеры кода:

- [Java 8 Stream API](https://ideone.com/PeIQMa)
- [Цикл `for-each`](https://ideone.com/hfOGRT)
- [Цикл по индексам](https://ideone.com/5vZUMj)

Comment: >> задан 3 сен '11 в 15:53 --- спасибо вам за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    numbers[i] = numberOfArrayElements.nextInt();
    sum = sum + numbers[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Sum of all elements from 1 to 1000
 */
final int sum = Stream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1).limit(1000).mapToInt(el -> el).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот 3 способа, от самого примитивного, до нормального. Сильно не критикуйте, сам только учусь.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

// сумма всех элементов массива, способ первый
class BlaBlaBla1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) sum += nums[i];
        System.out.println("1ый способ = " + sum);
    }
}

// сумма всех элементов массива, способ второй
class BlaBlaBla2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int sum = 0;

        sum = Arrays.stream(nums).sum();
        System.out.println("2ой способ = " + sum);
    }
}

// сумма всех элементов массива, способ третий: FOR-EACH
class BlaBlaBla3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int sum = 0;

        for (int x : nums) sum += x;
        System.out.println("3ий способ = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
public class test {
    public static int[] myArray;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myArray[] = {3, 5, 7, 12};
        System.out.print(sum(myArray));
    }
    public static int sum(int[] arr) {
        return sum(arr, 0, 0);
    }
    public static int sum(int[] arr, int sum, int count) {
        sum += arr[count];
        if (count < arr.length - 1) return sum(arr, sum, count + 1);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. ...правда, почему их тут от вас целых 3 штуки? :) ...прошло уже 4 года) я не занимаюсь Java, и не могу проверить ваш ответ. ...Но все равно благодарю вас, за вашу активность.

Comment: Незачто. Тренируюсь мозг.

Answer (score -1):

Считаем сумму двух чисел. Если находится, возвращаем `TRUE`:

```java
public class moed2AQuation2A2015 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] = {-2, 3, 5, 7, 12};
        System.out.println(sum2(arr, 19));
    }

    public static boolean sum2(int[] arr, int num) {
        return sum2(arr, num, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }

    public static boolean sum2(int[] arr, int n, int first, int second) {
        int summa = arr[first] + arr[second];
        if (summa == n) return true;
        if (second < first && first == second) return false;
        if (first < arr.length - 1 && second != first)
            return sum2(arr, n, first, second - 1) || sum2(arr, n, first + 1, second);
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
/**
 * calculate sum of  the array
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myArray[] = {3, 5, 7, 12};
    System.out.print(sum(myArray));
}

public static int sum(int[] arr) {
    return sum(arr, arr.length - 1);
}

public static int sum(int[] arr, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return arr[0];
    else
        return arr[n] + sum(arr, n - 1);
}
```