# Неравенство Коши на языке java

Tags: java, алгоритм, математика

Есть неравенство Коши. Пользователь задает значение `n`. Вроде всё легко, но никак не могу додуматься, каким образом записать так, чтобы от введенного `n` менялось количество `a` в неравенстве (`a` это рандомно полученные числа).

[image: неравенство Коши]

Comment: возможно стоит использовать массивы. и о какой функции идёт речь?

Comment: @diraria функция что на фото, уверен что без массивов тут никак, но я без понятия как сделать. даже если на словах обьясните, уже буду очень благодарен)

Comment: на фото не функция а неравенство) у функции есть параметры и возвращаемое значение. скажите, пожалуйста, что принимает функция и что должна возвращать?

Comment: Это неравенство всегда верно. Что должна делать программа?

Comment: @diraria ваша правда) это лишь часть задания. В конечном счете всё работает так: для введенного числа "n" нужно проверить это утверждение (что на фото) в 1000 различных наборах. Числа "a" генерируются случайным образом от 0 до 100. А в итоге нужно вывести все наборы где разница левой и правой частей неравенства менее 5%.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov описал чуть выше в комментарии

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a;  // рандомные числа
int aIncr = 0;  // здесь будет результат сложения всех "a"
int aMult = 1;  // здесь будет результат умножения всех "a"

// Где-то получено значение "n"
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    a = (рандомное число);
    aIncr += a;
    aMult *= a;
}
```

Осталось заменить выражения в скобках переменными "aIncr" и "aMult"

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, вопрос заключается в том, как работать с массивами.

- Создать массив определённого размера можно так:

  ```
  int[] array = new int[размер_массива];
  ```

  полученный массив будет заполнен нулями
- Обратиться к элементу по индексу можно так (индексы массива это числа от нуля до `размер_массива - 1`):

  ```
  array[индекс]
  ```
- Пробежаться по всему массиву можно с помощью цикла `for`:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) ...
  ```

  Например, вот так можно получить сумму всех элементов массива:

  ```
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
      sum += array[i];
  ```

  (кстати, [вот ещё несколько способов найти сумму элементов массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746556/227016))

Comment: Спасибо за информацию и помощь, насколько я понял мне нужно сделать так: нахожу суму деленную на "n" и произведение поднесенное на 1/n, сравниваю их на разницу неравенства. И весь этот кода вставляю в цикл, который выполнится 1000 раз. И уже из этих 1000 случаев я выбираю те, которые меня устраивают (разница менее 5%).