# Как Перебрать строки массива и получить их количество

Tags: java

хотел бы узнать, как мне примерно это написать на Java, я просто новичок.
Как Перебрать строки массива и получить их количество?
То есть добавить и как именно перебирать, подскажите

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти сумму чисел из массива в java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29831/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-java)

Comment: Нет, у меня совершено другое Михаил :)

Comment: @TerletskiyAlexander можешь уточнить что именно перебрать? добавь в вопрос, пожалуйста, пример массива

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Количество элементов `arrayName.length`,
добавить -

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
            arrayName[i]= someValue; //someValue - ваше значение

        }
```

[Вот здесь можно почитать подробнее](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/array.php)

Comment: Спасибо большое Владимир!

Answer (score 2):

Если при переборе индекс элемента неважен, то можно так

```
for (String str : arrayName) {
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

переберёт подряд все элементы.

Comment: Спасибо большое Евгений!